# Using widgets intregrated. PyQT with Tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter, pyqt, pyqt4

I have an image editor created in tkinter. However, I would add a floating widgets that exist in PyQt. Is there any way to run integrated tkinter with PyQt?

Answer (score 2):

I make a workaround that solved the problem. I used python subprocess for call the PyQT instance and the option QtCore.Qt.WindowStaysOnTopHint for app running on top of tkinter. It´s work.

but the best solution is to create a thread in python and call PyQt in this thread. In this case it is possible to pass an instance of tk for PyQt and make communication between the two. It´s work too. It´s fine.

Answer (score 1):

No, there is no way to combine widgets from PyQt and Tkinter in a single app. At least, not without resorting to running each toolkit in a separate thread or process. You can't embed the widgets of one into the widgets of the other.